# How to Run parallel builds in Jenkins slaves?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecs, jenkins-agent, jenkins-docker

I have a Jenkins master and I have configured Jenkins to create on-demand docker slaves in AWS ECS . This set up works good , when ever I run a build new slave is getting created in ECS and that slave is used to execute the build . My problem is I am not able to run concurrent builds in docker slaves .

When I run the second build the build is kept on Queue till the first build is completed . The second build is executed only after the first build is completed.

Is there a way to Run the builds concurrently by dynamically creating new docker slave in ECS?

I have followed this link to set up my docker slaves in AWS ECS 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0b53cdrujs

Answer (score 1):

There should be an "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" checkbox in the job configuration, under the General tab.  Try enabling that checkbox and building again.

Comment: tried that too . Even when the option is checked the builds are Queued instead of launching a docker container and executing a build.

Comment: Do you see multiple build executors as "Idle" in Jenkins?  Maybe you only have one executor active on your node.  Go to Manage Jenkins>Manage Nodes, and then click on the gear to the right of your node name (`master` in my case).  Make sure the "# of executors" is greater than 1.